# Eclipse - Maven does not add dependencies to project automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

After installing Eclipse on my new laptop I have not been able to have Eclipse download/display the dependency folder of a newly created project (http://prntscr.com/cg378c) without manually adding the following lines into the projects .classpath file

```
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
      <attributes>
          <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
          <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

After I manually add these lines to the file and update the maven project the dependencies are always updated automatically and such.

On my old Eclipse setup this was not an issue, so I am not sure what I did this time around to mess this up. All of my system variables are set and I have the m2e plugin installed along with the following maven installation(s) (http://prntscr.com/cg38gv).

I've tried to uninstall Eclipse fully but when I re-install it for some reason all of the plugins, including m2e, are still there.

How can I get Eclipse to automatically add the dependencies when I create a new project? Thanks!

Comment: You could "build" your eclipse project from command line with mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: I'd rather just have it so when I create a project the dependency 'folder' is automatically there like I had it on my previous eclipse installation :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the maven installation from my computer and completely re-installed eclipse yet again and now for some reason it is working. I guess my maven installation had an issue since that's the only difference between this re-installation and the previous one.